# Changing margins programatically on each paragraph in a docx file

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, docx

The application I'm building generates proposal documents for the company I work for. It's a complex system of copying, replacing, and deleting specific parts of DOCX files and XLSX files. I'm using XML powertools "DocumentBuilder" to assemble the document during the process of generating the proposal. The issue I'm having is as follows. Because of the age of the template files and the sheer number of options I must deal with Document builder ends up ignoring some of the margin settings throughout the length of the document. What I want to do to solve my formatting issue is iterate through each paragraph in the XML file and look for the properties, then drill into that element and check to see if I need to modify an existing margin entry or add a new one. My goal is for each paragraph element to have a section entry containing the default margin parameters for the document. This should alleviate the formatting issue. I can't seem to get it to work though. I've tried several different ways to change the XML file to no avail...

The current code Block I'm working with is as follows and is a work in progress so some code may not function properly:

```
Dim DocOutput As New WmlDocument(WP_OUTPUT)
        Using docStream As New OpenXmlMemoryStreamDocument(DocOutput)
        Using wpSource As WordprocessingDocument = docStream.GetWordprocessingDocument()

            Dim flag As Boolean
            Dim Section As New SectionProperties
            Dim Margin As New PageMargin

            Margin.Top = 720
            Margin.Right = 360
            Margin.Bottom = 2347
            Margin.Left = 1526
            Margin.Header = 432
            Margin.Footer = 432

            RevisionAccepter.AcceptRevisions(wpSource)
            Dim root As XElement = wpSource.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument.Root
            Dim body As XElement = root.LogicalChildrenContent.First
            For Each blockLevelContentElement As XElement In body.LogicalChildrenContent()
                If blockLevelContentElement.Name = W.p Then
                    For Each Paragraph As XElement In blockLevelContentElement.Elements()
                        If Paragraph.Name = W.pPr Then
                            For Each ParagraphProp As XElement In Paragraph.Elements()
                                flag = False
                                If ParagraphProp.Name = W.sectPr Then
                                    For Each SectionProp As XElement In ParagraphProp.Elements()
                                        If SectionProp.Name = W.pgMar Then
                                            SectionProp.SetAttributeValue(W.top, Margin.Top)
                                            SectionProp.SetAttributeValue(W.right, Margin.Right)
                                            SectionProp.SetAttributeValue(W.bottom, Margin.Bottom)
                                            SectionProp.SetAttributeValue(W.left, Margin.Left)
                                            SectionProp.SetAttributeValue(W.header, Margin.Header)
                                            SectionProp.SetAttributeValue(W.footer, Margin.Footer)
                                            flag = True
                                        End If
                                    Next
                                    If flag = False Then
                                        ParagraphProp.SetElementValue(W.sectPr, Margin)
                                        flag = True
                                    End If
                                End If
                            Next
                            If Not flag Then
                                Paragraph.Add(Section.AppendChild(Margin.CloneNode(False)))
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End Using
        Dim sources As New List(Of Source)
        Dim WmlHolder As New WmlDocument(docStream.GetModifiedWmlDocument)
        sources.Add(New Source(WmlHolder, True))
        DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources, WP_TEMP)
    End Using
```

Am I doing Something wrong when I'm attempting to write the correct values to the DOCX file? I've been struggling with this for about 4 days now. Is there perhaps a different type of object I need to be working with for this?

**UPDATE:**
I figured it out... I WAS using the wrong object model

This code works perfect

```
Try
        Dim DocOutput As New WmlDocument(WP_OUTPUT)
        Using docStream As New OpenXmlMemoryStreamDocument(DocOutput)
            Using wpSource As WordprocessingDocument = docStream.GetWordprocessingDocument()

                Dim flag As Boolean
                Dim Margin As New PageMargin

                Margin.Top = 721
                Margin.Right = 361
                Margin.Bottom = 2341
                Margin.Left = 1521
                Margin.Header = 431
                Margin.Footer = 431
                Dim body As Body = wpSource.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
                For Each paragraph In body.ChildElements
                    If paragraph.GetType().Name = "Paragraph" Then
                        For Each paragraphProp In paragraph.ChildElements
                            If paragraphProp.GetType().Name = "ParagraphProperties" Then
                                flag = False
                                For Each sect In paragraphProp.ChildElements
                                    If sect.GetType().Name = "SectionProperties" Then
                                        For Each sectProp In sect.ChildElements
                                            If sectProp.GetType().Name = "PageMargin" Then
                                                sectProp.Remove()
                                                sect.AppendChild(Margin.CloneNode(False))
                                                flag = True
                                            End If
                                        Next
                                        If Not flag Then
                                            sect.AppendChild(Margin.CloneNode(False))
                                            flag = True
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                Next
                                If Not flag Then
                                    paragraphProp.AppendChild(New SectionProperties().AppendChild(Margin.CloneNode(False)).CloneNode(False))
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    End If
                Next

            End Using
            Dim sources As New List(Of Source)
            Dim WmlHolder As New WmlDocument(docStream.GetModifiedWmlDocument)
            sources.Add(New Source(WmlHolder, True))
            DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources, WP_TEMP)
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

See the above code for the solution to this question